# Could we have a by hand proof that $H^{0,q}_{\bar{\partial}}(\mathbb{C}P^n)=0$ for $q>0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

It is well known that $H^{0,q}_{\bar{\partial}}(\mathbb{C}P^n)=0$ for $q>0$ and the usual proof is through Hodge decomposition. See Page 118 of Principles of Algebraic Geometry by Griffiths and Harris.

Could we have a direct, by hand proof that $H^{0,q}_{\bar{\partial}}(\mathbb{C}P^n)=0$ for $q>0$ without involving Hodge decomposition?

Comment: Are you going to allow yourself the Dolbeault isomorphism and consider $H^q(\Bbb P^n,\mathscr O)$?

Comment: Interestingly, to do this bare-hands just for $\Bbb P^1$, requires a "Runge extension" of the $\bar\partial$-lemma on disks in $\Bbb C$.